# Should .packages files be auto-generated for pub packages cached from git?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

The reason I'm asking it that I'm working on a package, actually flutter plugin and when I reference it local in my apps  `pubspec.yaml` using path:  everything works fine and I can see a `.packages` file being generated inside the local plugin workdir. Now if I now try to reference the plugin using git: in my apps pubspec,  flutter pub get is happy **BUT** when I try to run the app, the build fails with an error mesg:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on XYZ in debug mode...
/home/maksimlin/.pub-cache/git/edit_exif-3c87efc135c1269b5961ff73696a19e988132ad7/.packages does not exist.
Did you run "flutter pub get" in this directory?


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/maksimlin/fvm/versions/dev/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':edit_exif:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/maksimlin/fvm/versions/dev/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

and sure enough if I copy the `.packages` autogenerated file from my local plugin workdir into the the pub-cache location my app builds fine
So is something broken with pub auto-generating .packages for cached from git packages? or have I done something wrong with my plugin?

Unfortunately I can't seem to find much (any) documentation on the usage of .package files, especially for cached packages.

Comment: It turns out that I mistakenly added some extra config to the plugins gradle config that caused this issue: 

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Generated by pub on 2020-10-01 15:23:17.745081.
args:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.6.0/lib/
bloc:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-4.0.0/lib/
characters:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/characters-1.1.0-nullsafety.2/lib/
charcode:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/charcode-1.1.3/lib/
charts_common:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/charts_common-0.9.0/lib/
cloud_firestore:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.0/lib/
cloud_firestore_platform_interface:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-2.0.0/lib/
cloud_firestore_web:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-0.2.0/lib/
collection:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/collection-1.15.0-nullsafety.2/lib/
convert:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convert-2.1.1/lib/
crypto:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/crypto-2.1.5/lib/
custom_switch:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/custom_switch-0.0.1/lib/
dio:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-3.0.10/lib/
easy_localization:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/easy_localization-2.3.3/lib/
file:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file-5.2.1/lib/
firebase:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/
firebase_auth:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.18.0/lib/
firebase_auth_platform_interface:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-2.0.0/lib/
firebase_auth_web:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-0.3.0/lib/
firebase_core:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.5.0/lib/
firebase_core_platform_interface:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-2.0.0/lib/
firebase_core_web:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-0.2.0/lib/
flutter:file:///C:/Src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/
flutter_bloc:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_bloc-4.0.1/lib/
flutter_localizations:file:///C:/Src/flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/
flutter_web_plugins:file:///C:/Src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/
google_fonts:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_fonts-1.1.0/lib/
http:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/
http_parser:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http_parser-3.1.4/lib/
intl:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.1/lib/
js:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.2/lib/
logging:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/logging-0.11.4/lib/
matcher:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/matcher-0.12.9/lib/
material_design_icons_flutter:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/material_design_icons_flutter-4.0.5245/lib/
meta:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/
nested:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/nested-0.0.4/lib/
path:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/
path_provider:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.11/lib/
path_provider_linux:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_linux-0.0.1+2/lib/
path_provider_macos:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_macos-0.0.4+3/lib/
path_provider_platform_interface:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_platform_interface-1.0.2/lib/
pedantic:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pedantic-1.9.2/lib/
platform:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-2.2.1/lib/
plugin_platform_interface:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/plugin_platform_interface-1.0.2/lib/
process:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/process-3.0.13/lib/
provider:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-4.3.2/lib/
quiver:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/quiver-2.1.3/lib/
shared_preferences:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.8/lib/
shared_preferences_linux:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_linux-0.0.2+1/lib/
shared_preferences_macos:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_macos-0.0.1+10/lib/
shared_preferences_platform_interface:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/
shared_preferences_web:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_web-0.1.2+7/lib/
sky_engine:file:///C:/Src/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/
source_span:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/source_span-1.7.0/lib/
stack_trace:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_trace-1.9.5/lib/
string_scanner:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/string_scanner-1.0.5/lib/
term_glyph:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/term_glyph-1.1.0/lib/
typed_data:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/typed_data-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/
vector_math:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.1.0-nullsafety.2/lib/
xdg_directories:file:///C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/xdg_directories-0.1.0/lib/
website:lib/
```

This is my `.package` file here you can see that there is every package that I  have used to along with directory(file:///C:/Src/flutter is my directory).

`.package` is an autogenerated file so you can delete the older one and run `flutter pub get` so it will generate a newer one.

Comment: Thanks but that's *not* actually answering my question. I know what a . packages file looks like. I specifically want to know if there should be an auto generated . packages file *inside* the cached version of a package in .pub-cache that I included in my app from a git repo.

Comment: it is just a library location of packages and some material and Cupertino widgets's path.

Comment: obviously its a list of locations for locally cached packages,*MY QUESTION* is actually about if it should be autogenerated for packages cached from git inisde .pub-cache ? and if yes why it isn't being in my case?

Comment: `.packages` file does not exist in the GitHub repo because this file is mentioned in `.gitignore`.